# Simple module and homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Are the following statements equivalent?

i) $M$ is an $R$-simple module.

ii) Every $R$-homomorphism (nonzero) from $M$ to an $R$-module $N$ is a monomorphism.

iii) Every $R$-homomorphism (nonzero) from an $R$-module $N$ to $M$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: Hint: kernels and images are submodules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

Hint: You can easily see that considering the kernel, image resp. of an $R$-homomorphism. Conversely, if assumptions $ii)$ or $iii)$ hold for such $R$-homomorphisms, then $M$ has to be simple, where you can consider the possible submodules of $M$ to check.

Comment: With your hints, I can solve my problem myseft. Thanks a lot.